# Why are gradle build packagingOptions needed?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

In my gradle file, I have the following:

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
}
```

According to the documentation:

```
/**
 * Adds an excluded paths.
 * @param path the path, as packaged in the APK
 */
```

What does this mean? Could someone give me a real life example of why these exclusions would need to be made?

Comment: If 2+ libraries contain those files, you'll get a build conflict. Since you don't need those files in your APK, the typical solution is to exclude them.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27977396/android-studio-duplicate-files-copied-in-apk-meta-inf-dependencies-when-compile

Comment: Is there a difference between setting this under `android{ buildTypes{ packagingOptions{...} } }` vs `android{ packagingOptions{...} }`?

Comment: the `packagingOptions` closure is not available on the `buildTypes` block.  Your creating a new `buildType` by placing it there

Answer (score 24):

If you were to change the extension of a few `aar` files to `zip` and open them eventually you will have two `aar` files with files that with the same path.

```
SomeDependency-A.aar
-META-INF/LICENSE
...

SomeDependency-B.aar
-META-INF/LICENSE
...
```

When the `aar` dependencies are merged it fails because it tries to add the file `LICENSE` and it already exists.

We resolve this by excluding the duplicated files

```
android {
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

For [Kotlin DSL](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html) (build.gradle.kts) and [Android Gradle Plugin](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin) (AGP) version 7.0.0 and higher the `exclude` method is deprecated in favor of the `resources.excludes` property:

```kotlin
android {
  // ...
  packaging { // or packagingOptions in AGP < 8.x
    resources.excludes += "META-INF/LICENSE*"
    resources.excludes += "META-INF/NOTICE.txt"
    // OR
    // resources.excludes += setOf(
    //   "META-INF/LICENSE*",
    //   "META-INF/NOTICE.txt"
    // )
  }
}
```

Comment: And further than that, with version 8.0.0 "packagingOptions" is deprecated in favour of "packaging".