# For what purpose is packagingOptions used?

Tags: android, kotlin, build.gradle

Something I noticed in build.gradle when I use android studio canary.

What exactly is its intended use?

```
packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}' // ??? 
        }
    }
```

Comment: so basically its for times when we use multiple libraries then in those libraries there ight be some things that are used multiple time in project

Comment: This answer helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27989570/1631197

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure how to link comments, but this is what **commonsware** on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35417464/why-are-gradle-build-packagingoptions-needed):

> "If 2+ libraries contain those files, you'll get a build conflict.
> Since you don't need those files in your APK, the typical solution is
> to exclude them."

For a more detailed answer, I found [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27989570/1631197) very good.

P.S. - I tried marking this as duplicate but I don't think I did it right. ^_^;;